# Multiple parameters in Factory Method Pattern

Tags: java, parameters, factory-method

I'm trying to use Factory Method Pattern to create different objects, but i have several doubts. Let me show you the scenario:

```
public class ObjectFactory{

    public static IObject createObject(Param1 p1, Param2 p2, Param3 p3){
        if (p1.getName('name1')){
            return new Object1(p1,p2,p3);
        }else{
            return new Object2(p1, p2);
        }
    }
}

public interface IObject{   
    void doSomething();
}

public class Object1 implements IObject {
    public Object1(Param1 p1, Param2 p2, Param3 p3){}
}

public class Object2 implements IObject {
    public Object1(Param1 p1, Param2 p2){}
}
```

Im a bit confused with the Param3 in the ObjectFactory's createObject method. I always have this param, but sometimes it makes no sense. 
I don't like this because if some day I add more objects with different params, I will need to add too many params to the method signature.

I was thinking in defining:
public static IObject createObject(Param1 p1, Param2 p2, Param3 p3) 
public static IObject createObject(Param1 p1, Param2 p2)
but then it isn't a Factory Method Pattern, because invoker must know which method has to be executed.

Do you know any solution to deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the Builder Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the factory is actually making the design simpler? Your use case sample is very abstract so it's hard to tell, but if the client must already know the various dependencies explicitely perhaps you should also let it choose the implementation?

If you find yourself passing the type of object the client wants (as an enum or a string) to the factory then chances are that you shouldn't be using a factory at all, unless there are multiple implementations per type. There are exceptions, but that could serve as a guideline.

However, it may also be that the client knows the configuration, but doesn't know and shouldn't know how that translates to an implementation. In that case using the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) could simplify your API if you have many configuration option permutations.